# Query inside a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using php with Mysql.
I want to know what really is wrong with query inside a query, what if i am not that much comfortable with using the INNER JOIN , and rather prefer writing multiple queries.
Am i doing something terribly wrong, or is it just to make it visually sound?

What I mean is...

```
$query="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USER_ID=1";
$data=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$query2="select * from TAble2 where some_id='{$row['user_id']}'";
$data1=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($data1);
// and then use $row1['column_name']
```

Comment: Do you mean a "sub-query"? In most cases, sub-query performance is terrible and the same (or equivalent) query can be written using other means. What is it you're trying to do (post code)?

Comment: sub-query has worse performance when IN clause query returns a large amount of results

Comment: @Shivan Sub-queries have worse performance in general. For the case you've stated, an `EXISTS` clause is generally better than `IN`

Comment: @Phil basically i meant, $query="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USER_ID=1";
$data=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$query2=select * from TAble2 where some_id='$row['user_id']";
$data1=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($data1);

and then use $row1['column_name']

i know this i clumsy to read/write, but what other ill effects do these have?

Comment: @Karan Best if you edit your question to post more code. I've done it for you this time

Comment: @Phil anyways, could you tell me if i use the joins for these queries, what would i gain?

Comment: @Phil, are you saying that you made up Karan's code example?

Comment: @Golez Nope, copied it from their comment above. I just can't stand reading code in the SO comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit to combining as much as possible into a single query as opposed to iterating nested cursors is that round trips to the DB are relatively expensive.

Using the nested cursors method in your question, you are preparing and executing *n + 1* SQL statements, where *n* is the number of records in the initial result set.

Where you to combine those queries with a join, you would only be preparing and executing one statement, no matter how large the result set.

```
SELECT T1.foo, T1.bar, T2.baz
FROM `TABLE` T1
INNER JOIN `Table2` T2 ON T1.user_id = T2.some_id
WHERE T1.user_id = 1
```

You're also placing less load on the database itself, particularly where statement caching is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

You should post some code before we can help you with your specific problem.

However, I would say that not being comfortable with doing something is generally not an excuse not to do it.  Instead, you should read all you can about `JOIN`s so that you *are* comfortable, and then there won't be a problem.

`JOIN`s are very powerful, and there are many things that you cannot do in MySQL without them.  When you say query within a query, I assume you mean doing something like

```
SELECT
   postid
FROM
   Post
WHERE
   userid IN (
      SELECT
         userid
      FROM
         User
      WHERE
         username = ?
   )
```

Isn't this much more complicated than

```
SELECT
   postid
FROM
   Post
   NATURAL JOIN User
WHERE
   username = ?
```

Comment: disagree. I know JOIN is more powerful, but for me, subquery is easier to understand than those INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, OUTER JOIN, NATURAL JOIN, etc.

Comment: @Shivan clearly you didn't read my answer very well.  You need to read about these JOINs until you *are* comfortable with them as they are very powerful.  Are you really intimidated by there being at least four different types of JOIN?  Btw a NATURAL JOIN in mysql is an inner join.  Right and Left joins are both outer joins.  There's no real reason to use a right join either.  That wipes two of your list already!

Comment: @Shivan It's not a case of using the "more powerful" option, it's about using the DBMS correctly

Comment: More importantly, JOINs and subqueries are not interchangeable. You can not add columns to a result set without a join.

Comment: @eaolson: The OP might be talking about correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause. (That is possibly why they have mentioned multiple queries as opposed to INNER JOIN.)